# Связь с базой данных phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

Не могу связаться с Базой данных в phpmyadmin пытаюсь создать автоматическую форму заполнения таблицы. Но при отправки сообщения выдает ошибку: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /var/www/r0058300/data/www/fang21.ru/report.php on line 25. Все перепроверил но не получается! Помогите!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ru" xml:lang="ru" />
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>космические пришельцы похищали меня-собщения о похищениях</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Космичиские пришельцы похищали меня - собщение о похищении </h2>

<?php
$first_name = $_POST ['firstname'];
$last_name = $_POST ['lastname'];
$when_it_happend = $_POST [ 'whenithappend' ];
$how_many = $_POST ['howmany'];
$how_long = $_POST [ 'howlong' ];
$what_they_did = $_POST ['whattheydid'];
$alien_description = $_POST [ 'aliendescription' ];
$fang_spotted = $_POST [ 'fangspotted' ];
$email = $_POST [ 'email' ];
$other = $_POST ['other'];

$dbc = mysqli_connect (http://fang21.ru/myadmin, ..., ...,  r0058300_arty21)
 or die ('ошибка соединения с MySQL-сервером');

$query = "INSERT INTO aliens_abduction (first_name, last_name, when_it_happend,     how_long, " .
" how_many, alien_description, what_they_did, fang_spotted, other, email) " .

" VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$when_it_happend', '$how_long',     '$how_many', " . 
" '$alien_description', '$what_they_did', '$fang_spotted', '$other', '$email') " ;

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
or die ('ошибка при выполнение запросов к базе данных.');

mysqli_close($dbc);

echo 'Спасибо за заполнение формы.<br />';
echo 'Ваше Имя: ' . $name . '<br />';
echo 'Вы были похищины ' .  $when_it_happend;
echo ' и отсутствовали в течение ' . $how_long . '<br />';
echo 'Их было: ' . $how_many . '<br />';
echo 'Опишите их: ' . $alien_description . '<br />';
echo 'Эти существа с вами: ' . $what_they_did . '<br />';
echo 'Видели вы мою собаку Фенга? ' . $fang_spotted. '<br />';
echo 'Дополнительная информация: ' . $other . '<br />';
echo 'Ваш адрес электронной почты: ' . $email;
?>

</body>
</html>

Пароль и логин я заменил ... специально, в реальности я их прописываю.
```

Comment: а 25 строка ваша где? а то по этому коду не очень понятно, ведь может быть переформатировано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /var/www/r0058300/data/www/fang21.ru/report.php on line 25

дословно: ошибка парсинга, неожиданный символ ":" в файле ... на строке 25

идем и ищем:

```
mysqli_connect (http://fang21.ru/myadmin ...
```

1) адрес передается как строка, т.е. в кавычках
2) вы уверены, что по этому адресу сущесвует подключение mysql в принципе?

Comment: Обратился в тех.поддержку они отвечают что, дословно: Укажите,  пожалуйста: localhost. Как это можно понять?

Comment: Хотя до этого я у них спрашивал адресс, они мне его и дали http://fang21.ru/myadmin

Comment: @Arty21 mysqli_connect('localhost', ...

Comment: Ну так и понимать, вместо "http://fang21.ru/myadmin", указываем localhost

Comment: Опоздал :) http://fang21.ru/myadmin это phpmyadmin, а не имя хоста для соединения с БД!

Comment: Спасибо вам! все получилось!

Answer (score 0):

В кавычки все поля возьмите:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```